# Consistent random state within multiple jobs of KMeans/RF

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

My problem is that the KMeans-Algorithm from the sklearn module clustering produces different results if I use multiple jobs instead of just one, even though I did set a random seed. As I need the results to be identical for the same inputs, I  called the KMeans function as follows

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
k_means = KMeans(n_clusters=k, init='k-means++', random_state=1, n_jobs=-1)
```

Problem with this is that this produces different (and worse in my calculation overall actually) results than if I do not use multiple jobs but just one. Can anyone tell me how to fix this? If tried setting a `RandomState` instance like

```
    rand_state = np.random.RandomState(1)
    k_means = KMeans(n_clusters=k, init='k-means++', random_state=rand_state, n_jobs=-1)
```

but this also does not give consistent results with the same function with just one job.

Also, as I do have to do some quite heavy clustering on lots of data, I'd really like to use multiple jobs to save time. And I do have the same issue when using random forest regression btw.

**Toy example for clarification**

So the function I am using is as follows:

```
def find_cluster_centers(timeseries, k):
    k_means = KMeans(n_clusters=k, init='k-means++', random_state=1, n_jobs=-1)
    k_means.fit(timeseries)
    return k_means.cluster_centers_
```

I then created a random matrix and used the clustering method one time with `n_jobs=1` and one time with `n_jobs=-1`. The result did differ!

This one is with `n_jobs=1`

```
random_ts = np.random.normal(0,1,(10000,100))
single_job = find_cluster_centers(random_ts, 100)  
single_job _df = pd.DataFrame(single_job )
single_job _df.head()

         0         1         2         3         4         5         6   \
0 -0.848288  0.589338 -0.006344  0.257509 -0.119400  0.000149  0.262761   
1 -0.629481 -0.159716  0.590887 -0.343553  1.229933 -0.353534 -0.031462   
2  0.390420 -0.407103  0.032059 -0.213350 -0.145259  0.897559  0.259399   
3 -0.278780  0.028879 -0.287944 -0.219377  0.296087 -0.312260  0.108674   
4  0.152551  0.060320  0.222156  0.290888 -0.279436 -0.290054  0.374626
```

This is with `n_jobs=-1`

```
multiple_jobs = find_cluster_centers(random_ts, 100)
multiple_jobs _df = pd.DataFrame(multiple_jobs )
multiple_jobs _df.head()

         0         1         2         3         4         5         6   \
0  0.112666  0.206470  0.212597 -0.016386  0.086566  0.287404 -0.109466   
1  0.344165  0.224839  0.106922  0.385593  0.065500 -0.089228 -0.489109   
2 -0.520918 -0.165296 -0.018160  0.201272  0.096660  0.665532  0.061834   
3  0.325803  0.164303  0.417824 -0.149116  0.512074  0.335293  0.367367   
4  0.278681  0.077819 -0.078964  0.355309  0.129788 -0.333567  0.384981
```

Answer (score 0):

When using multiple jobs, a set of seeds is generated for each of the parallel jobs.  Each job is initialized and runs `n_init` times with the best of those initializations getting reported back to the parallel job pool.  The best of the jobs from the job pool is reported used as the final output.

In other words, multiple jobs does not split the tasks, rather it creates multiple instances with different initialization seeds and returns the best of the instances.  It is however, reproducible.  Using the same `random_state` will produce the same clusters when using a single or multiple jobs.

It won't produce the same clusters as using a single job, that is correct. Using multiple jobs with have many more calculations of the cluster locations and will give the best of those results. It should be a better centroid location

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  
I still cannot understand why the results differ. In my understanding, the algorithm does calculate the `n_init` times the centroids and returns the best one. If multiple jobs are wanted, this step is calculated in parallel (stated in the documentation of kmeans). Does this mean the `n_init=10` are calulated in a split way, meaning 2 cores do 5 calculations each or in a "multiplicative" way, meaning 2 cores each do 10 calculations? In both cases I do not understand why the results should differ. Plus why multiple jobs are faster if they do not split the task